# Animated plots MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, matlab-figure

I have problem to produce animated plots, using MATLAB.

I want to plot **my signal y** as a function of **my time x** (that i keep in two separate variables) and then produce an animation of it, seeing variations of my signal according to time.

At the end, I would like to produce both a succession of ".tif" images (for reading it in imageJ) and a ".avi" movie file.

It will really help me if someone can show me the way, because i try to do it by myself using MATLAB Help and forums, but i failed every time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this would be to update your plot data within a loop, and use [`getframe`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) or a similar function to grab the current screen and save it to a file with [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) or [`VideoWriter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html).

**imwrite**

With [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) it is important that if you want to write multi-frame data (for either a TIFF or GIF) you want to use the `'WriteMode'` parameter and set it to `'append'` so that you simply add the new frame to the image. On the first time through the loop you **don't** want to append since that would append to an existing image that may already exist.

**getframe**

As far as [`getframe`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html), it grabs a screenshot of the specified figure and returns a struct containing a colormap and the RGB image as `cdata`. This is the thing that you want to write to either your video or your multi-frame image.

**VideoWriter**

For writing to video, you'll use the [`VideoWriter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html) class which behaves a little differently. The main steps are:

1. Create the object

   `vid = VideoWriter('filename.avi');`
2. Open the object

   `vid.open() % or open(vid)`
3. Write some data using [`writeVideo`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.writevideo.html)

   `vid.writeVideo(data)`
4. Close the Video

   `vid.close()`

Then you can call `writeVideo` as many times as you want and each time it will add an additional frame.

**Summary**

Here is a demo which brings all of that together and writes a multi-frame TIFF as well as an AVI.

```
% Example data to plot
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
y = sin(x);


% Set up the graphics objects
fig = figure('Color', 'w');
hax = axes();
p = plot(NaN, NaN, 'r', 'Parent', hax, 'LineWidth', 2);
set(hax, 'xlim', [0, 2*pi], 'ylim', [-1 1], 'FontSize', 15, 'LineWidth', 2);

% Create a video object
vid = VideoWriter('video.avi')
vid.open()

% Place to store the tiff
tifname = 'image.tif';

for k = 1:numel(x)
    set(p, 'XData', x(1:k), 'YData', y(1:k));

    % Grab the current screen
    imdata = getframe(fig);

    % Save the screen grab to a multi-frame tiff (using append!)
    if k > 1
        imwrite(imdata.cdata, tifname, 'WriteMode', 'append')
    else
        imwrite(imdata.cdata, tifname);
    end

    % Also write to an AVI
    vid.writeVideo(imdata.cdata);
end

% Close the video
vid.close()
```

**Results** (as an animated GIF)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Suever it works pretty fine! I just have to add 'Compression', 'none' for writing the .tif. Like this " imwrite(imdata.cdata, tifname,'Compression','none','WriteMode', 'append')
imwrite(imdata.cdata, tifname,'Compression','none');